# Character modeling:Front view model is not aligned with Side view model

Tags: modeling

I am new to Blender.I am following a tutorial found on youtube.I have created a model for my character's face in front view.But it is not aligned with side view/right view.That means, it's position on the right view is so much below the character's body let alone in the exact position on the face where it should be.Can I[image] align it or should i start over?﻿

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Move the image using these values:
[image]

Comment: By saying "do this" without explaining why, it only helps OP, and will not help any other Stack Exchange readers.

Comment: Thank you for that, it really inspires me to continue helping people.