# Modeling character in side view

Tags: modeling, 3d-view

I am totally new to Blender.Following a tutorial found over internet, I have started to modeling a character on my own.I have created face loop for front view.But the problem is, I think I can not model it on the side view.I am facing some problem regarding this.I attach image to depict the problem.Please,help me out.[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you send me the blend file so I can take a look (go to http://pasteall.org/blend/)

Comment: It's not all that clear what is your problem, If it's a free tutorial on the web please add the link so we can see what you are seeing. To share the .blend on this site please use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Can you explain what "I think I can not model it on the side view" means? What problem are you encountering that means you can't model like this? Please [edit] your question to add this additional information.

Comment: http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=47234 .Here is my .blend file. And the tutorial link I have been watching: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0QT1GNMevfc&t=75s .Problem arises on 11:10 mark

Comment: @RayMairlot I am new to blender.So,some concepts are not clear to me.I have attached a youtube link in the comment above.He starts to do "somethng" on the side view on 11:10 mark.But when I try to do so,I jeopardize it.Hope,I have succeeded to elucidate the matter to you.I have also add my .blender file on the question and also on the comment above.Take a look.Have a good day!

Comment: @m.ardito take a look on the edited question.I have attached my .blender file.

Comment: @Ivan    take a look on the edited question.I have attached my .blender file.

Comment: How is this different from your [other question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/85083/character-modelingfront-view-model-is-not-aligned-with-side-view-model)?

Comment: You extruded it to the wrong direction.

Comment: @Asm Arman without having the same reference images (you didn't pack those in the .blend) is difficult to repeat your exact steps, but it seems that you just have to select each vertex on the front view and move it in the side view along Y, reaching the intended point... why you say that "you can't"? what prevents you to do so?

Comment: @AsmArman what exactly do you mean by "*I can not model it on the side view*" could you clarify what what you mean? Maybe you should start with a simpler task your a beginner tutorial instead.

Answer (score 1):

I took a look at your blend file. If I understand correctly you want to model a the little guy with faces. You started by the front and have trouble continuing on with the sides. I have provided you the modified blend file. Please check it out and tell me if you find anything interesting.

I have fixed the extrusion you've made. It seems like you selected the wrong faces to extrude. What you need to do is select vertices you want to extrude, hit E and pull them back towards the back of the head.

Again if that wasn't the answer you were looking for, don't hesitate to tell me and I will help.

[blender file download link](http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=47235)

[image]

**Some tips:**

- when extruding you can snap vectices to other vertices by pressing
  `Ctrl`. Your vertex will then snap to the nearest vertex. [wiki extrude tool](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/duplicating/extrude.html)
- avoid having Ngons by keeping all faces as rectangles. This will help you model the little man.
- You can select all model and click on `W` then click on `Remove doubles`

***EDIT***

Ok so the video tells you to model the general shape of the face in 2D, then at [11:10](https://youtu.be/0QT1GNMevfc?t=11m10s) he starts giving it depth by pulling forward some vertices. It's very easy: Be careful to have your side reference placed in the middle like so:[image] then select one vertice from the "middle line": [image]

And pull it foward on the Y axis. until it maches your reference.[image]

Repeat this select/pull process for each vertice of this line.

Comment: Ivan, thank you for your help.In the comment section, I have attached a youtube video link.In that video, the modeling of the side part was quiet hard.I don't understand what I have done wrong.In video, he extrude the vertices on the upper portion of the nose.But trying that same thing got me into mess.Would you please check the video out on 11:10 mark? And again thanks a lot for your answer.Really appreciate it.

Comment: I don't understand what is snapping and why should I do it.Please give me a basic idea about snapping.And it would be help full if you provide me with some easy to understand and to the point,precise blender tutorial materials.

Comment: Ok, take a look at my edit

Comment: Ivan, thanks again for your co-operation.My problem is when I want to do something just like the instructor did on 11:10 mark, I face some problems.Like when I tried to extrude vertices it become messy.I think I should upload another version of. blender with  side view somehow processed.Then you can understand the problem.What do you say?

Comment: I don't really know how to help now. You should start the tutorial again and follow as much as possible your instructor. It's very important to do exactly what he does because if you start adding triangles and Ngones you will have a harder time following him after. Just take a look at his mesh, he has only squares. If you want me to really help you, the best way would be to video capture the part were you extrude so I can really see the problem you're facing.

Comment: Yeah,video capturing would be a great idea.Would you please tell me where can I share this video with you?

Comment: Looks like https://uploadfiles.io/ could work out

Comment: Ok, I wll let you know.